# Interactively running Python script in R Studio - how to install a package?

Tags: python, r, import, reticulate

I installed `reticulate` package. I created Python script in R-Studio

```
import os
import pandas as pd
```

Running first line bring Python console `>>>` and runs fine. The second line generates `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`.So I am guessing I need to install `pandas` (or maybe activate environment, since miniconda is installed) I tried the following in Terminal of R-Studio:

```
pip
pip3
conda
```

All of them returned: `bash: <relavant_command> command not found...`

How can execute this line `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **py_install** from **reticulate**.

https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_install.html